# nodejs req.body undefined in case of ajax post requests

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, undefined

Strange issue and I have no explanation to that. I create ajax post request

```
 $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/like",  
        data: {"topic": "123123"},  
        success: function(dataString) {               
            console.log('123123'); 
        }  
    });
```

Or like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp.open("POST", "/like", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

on server side (NodeJs) I have simple code

```
app.post('/like', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(201).send('+1')
});
```

what I dont understand, is why I receive all the time undefined when I send ajax post request.

[image]

Comment: You need to use a body parser https://nodejs.dev/learn/get-http-request-body-data-using-nodejs

Comment: Thanks Mark, it works. Please post as a reply, I will mark resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a body parser, see: nodejs.dev/learn/get-http-request-body-data-using-nodejs